# What are the minimum specs for Ubuntu server to host a subversion repository?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, svn

I need to build an server (Ubuntu 9.10 server) to host source control (subversion) from my house.  What are the minimum specs (processor and RAM) to do this with good performance?  I'll need to buy some new parts from newegg and just need enough to get by.  It may also serve as a file server for other things in the future, but nothing intensive like media streaming.  I only need about a 1GB repository, and 2 or 3 users.

Comment: How big is the repository going to be?  How many users?

Comment: edited this in the original post - 1GB, 2 or 3 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a large repository or lots of users doing full checkouts multiple times per day, you really don't need much at all. I ran a decent-sized repository (~20GB maybe? 4-5 regular users) on a Pentium 3 with I think 2GB of RAM. The only complaint anybody ever had was that the initial checkout of some repositories (typically the one that was >6GB) was too long.

After the initial checkout, doing checkins/updates within individual directories speeds everything up noticeably anyway.

Comment: Great this is what i wanted to know.  I only have 2-3 users for now.  And I won't have nearly 6GB of data (at least not at first).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a VM set for serving my personal svn repository.  The VM has 192MB of RAM, and a 3GB virtual hard disk.  is completely idle 99.9% of the day.  I am using svn+ssh to access the repository.  At the moment the size of my repository is only about 5MB.  I am the only user.  I figure I do few updates/commits each day.

If you have lots more users, have a very active project(s) then you may need more.

Answer (score 1):

I have a virtual machine with 10 GB HDD totally and 512 MB RAM. For repositories, we have near 30 projects from more than 2 years and used by about 10 users day by day.
My PC is Pentium 4 3.0 GHz. I think it's a useful advice to you. Good luck!